# Unpacking parameters for a simulation

Tags: python, parameters, scipy, emcee

I do a lot of ODE simulations and I work with a few python parameter optimization tools (e.g. scipy.optimize.minimize, [emcee](http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/)) that require parameters to be passed in as a list. This makes them very cumbersome, as I have to refer to the parameters as `params[0]`, `params[1]`, etc. as opposed to more intuitive names that actually describe their role in the simulation. My solution to this so far has been something along the lines of this:

```
k1 = 1.0 
k2 = 0.5
N = 0.01

params = [k1,k2,N]

def sim(params,timerange):
    k1 = params[0]
    k2 = params[1]
    N = params[2]

    # run the simulation
```

This is really kludgey and is unsatisfactory for a number of reasons. Whenever I need to add new parameters to the simulation I have to modify the params list and change how I'm manually unpacking the list inside the simulate function; wastes some time making new references each round of simulating, etc.

I'm wondering if there's a sane, non-kludgey solution for defining the parameters with names, passing them to a function as a list, and then referring to them by those same names inside the list.

Comment: Could you give a bit more explanation of what you do inside the `sim` function? Specifically I was hoping to see where you call the scipy or emcee functions so we have a better idea of what needs to be passed around. My intuition tells me using `*args` and `**kwargs` will get you where you need to go, but without more info I can't be sure.

Comment: Fair. Those functions aren't actually called from inside sim. All sim does is return the instantaneous values of a system of ODEs, which are used by the scipy `odeint` function to determine the evolution of the system I'm interested in. This, in turn is called from a function that calculates the error between the simulation and some data, which is called by emcee or `optimize.minimize`. The job of these last two is to minimize the error function; the reason I need to do the list unpacking is because they require the parameters they are tuning to be passed in a list.

Comment: `*args` won't work because then each parameter is passed as a separate argument, I need them all passed in as elements of a single list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sim(params,timerange):
    k1,k2,N = params
```

Is what you want I think ..,.. if you added an extra param you would just add it after N ... but it would not be an optional argument

or maybe better

```
def sim(*params,**kwargs):
    timerange = kwargs.get('timerange',default_timerange)
    K1,K2,N = params #assuming you know you have exactly 3

#then call it like so
sim(k1,k2,N,timerange=(-100,100))
```

Comment: I think your first one should be helpful, thanks! The second won't because the problem I have is that the `sim` function is required by the optimizers I'm using to be called with a list of parameter values as input (as opposed to each parameter as a separate input).

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I think you mean `k1,k2,N = params`.  With the *, it results in a syntax error.

Comment: yeah ... sorry i was on autopilot when I added this :P

Answer (score 1):

I usually do what Joran suggests in his answer:

```
def sim(params, timerange):
    k1, k2, N = params
    ...
```

but you can also do this:

```
def sim((k1, k2, N), timerange):
    ...
```

(At least, that works in Python 2.7.  I haven't tried it with other Python versions.)  I tested the idea with `scipy.integrate.odeint`, `scipy.integrate.ode` and `scipy.optimize.minimize`, and it worked fine.  For example, in the following code, you can use either `cost` or `cost2` as the first argument to `minimize`:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def cost(z, a, b):
    x, y = z
    c = (x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2
    return c

def cost2((x, y), a, b):
    c = (x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 5.0
    b = 1.5
    x0 = 4.2
    y0 = 1.5
    sol = minimize(cost2, (x0, y0), args=(a,b))
    print sol['x']
```